# Google Search Engine custom api implementation to enterprise?

Tags: google-search-api, google-search-appliance

I have started a small IT service company recently in India. I was approached by an Big Enterprise asking to design a custom search engine (for internal/web usage) using the Google's custom search engine api.

1. it has to fetch info from a specific set of websites (internal websites / common web search)
2. if a particular website is selected before search, it should display the info from that website only.
3. Enterprise has a webpages that can be accessed with authentication. when user logged-in, the search has to fetch info from those authenticated webpages as well.
4. the contents should be segregated into images, books, movies, music, etc.
5. auto complete and search while typing
6. once we finish this design, may have to run it as a android application using phone gap(cordova lib).

My Questions:

1. Is Google allow me to do implementation for the Enterprise (they ready to use and pay Usage Charge for using Google search api), and Can I charge the enterprise for implementation and support (agreement will be made between my company and enterprise)?
2. Is Google provide ad free search results for custom search? If not can we do restriction on the result?
3. Is Google search engine can be extended to android app?
4. If your answer is "No" for above questions, if I develop search engine solution on my own, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Google Custom Search is searching only publicly available documents. For internal websites, you can check out Google Search Appliance: http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/products/gsa.html